# How do I reference a cell from a Google Spreadsheet in a Google Document

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to create a Google Spreadsheet and reference a cell(-range) from that spreadsheet in a Google Document.

Basically, I want the spreadsheet to be a variable holder where I can input data to the fields I want, and the document displays this data in a format that looks better. Very much like creating a report to display my data.

How would this be accomplished?

p.s. I know how to reference a cell from one spreadsheet to another, this is NOT what I want. I want to reference a cell(-range) from a spreadsheet but I want to have the reference in a document.

Comment: That's not possible. The only way to do that, is to use Google Apps Script.

Comment: I tagged it [google-drive] because there wasn't a [google-scripts] a [google-docs] nor a [google-spreadsheet]. Is there a more effective tag I should have used? I'm new to the webapps stackexchange group.

Comment: @pnuts I don't even see your original comment that I responded to?! I forget the ping (@) thing, gotta start remembering that one...

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in a [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62847/how-do-i-reference-a-cell-from-a-google-spreadsheet-in-a-google-document#comment50856_62847), "That's not possible. The only way to do that, is to use Google Apps Script"